# java - putting a set of variables into a loop without arrays

Tags: java, arrays

Today I wanted to use the java code below and it did not work of course.
I know that in order to process the idea below I should create a basic array which should include all my String variables but... I am wondering is there an option to change my code and process the code without the mentioned basic array ?

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

String variable1 = "text1";
String variable2 = "text2";
String variable3 = "text3";

for ( int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ){
array.add(i, variable + i ); // error 
}
```

thank you in advance !

Comment: What's wrong with just `array.add("text1")`?

Comment: `variable1`, `variable2`, and `variable3` should just be an array (variable[]). I see what you are trying to do with `variable+i`, but it will not do what you are wanting. You want to use an array.

Comment: You are trying to add at index i (which is first 1), hence the error.

Comment: IndexOutOfBoundsException - if the index is out of range (index < 0 || index > size())... index here is 1 and size 0.

Comment: My comments assume "variable" does exists in your code (and is probably equals to "text" and that variable1,2,3 are there to help point what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

This is the only reasonable way, if we ignore fact that your `array` is already a collection.

```
ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<String>();

String[] variables=new String[3];
variables[0] = "text1";
variables[1] = "text2";
variables[2] = "text3";

for ( int i = 0; i < 3; i++ ){
    array.add(variables[i]); // error 
}
```

Comment: `String variables[0]`?

Comment: @AndyTurner ahh yes my mistake. You could simply edit the post IMHO :)